# how to see the definition or sql code of function() in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am learning postgresql.

I created a function and it works properly as it is called. However I do have trouble with looking back the sql code.

Would you mind helping me to find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `pg_proc` catalogue](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/catalog-pg-proc.html) :

```
select proname, prosrc from pg_proc where proname= 'my_function';
```

Or from the psql terminal, use [the `\sf` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-psql.html) :

```
\sf my_function
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe : right ! I edited my answer, thanks for pointing this out.